# what is the source of this error: python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
#census_df.head()

def answer_seven():

    census_df_1 = census_df[(census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50)].set_index('CTYNAME')
    census_df_1['highest'] = census_df_1[['POPESTIAMTE2010','POPESTIAMTE2011','POPESTIAMTE2012','POPESTIAMTE2013','POPESTIAMTE2014','POPESTIAMTE2015']].max()
    census_df_1['lowest'] =census_df_1[['POPESTIAMTE2010','POPESTIAMTE2011','POPESTIAMTE2012','POPESTIAMTE2013','POPESTIAMTE2014','POPESTIAMTE2015']].min()
    x = abs(census_df_1['highest'] - census_df_1['lowest']).tolist()
    return x[0] 
answer_seven()
```

This is trying to use the data from `census.csv` to find the counties that have the largest absolute change in population within 2010-2015(POPESTIMATES), I wanted to simply find the difference between abs.value of max and min value for each year/column. You must return a string. also `[(census_df['SUMLEV'] ==50)]` means only counties are taken  as they are set to 50. But the code gives an error that ends with

> KeyError: "['POPESTIAMTE2010' 'POPESTIAMTE2011' 'POPESTIAMTE2012'
>   'POPESTIAMTE2013'\n 'POPESTIAMTE2014' 'POPESTIAMTE2015'] not in index"

Am  I indexing the wrong data structure? I'm really new to datascience and coding.

Comment: this looks supicious `'POPESTIAMTE2013'\n` you have a new line embedded in your list of column names for some reason, post the output from `print(census_df.columns.tolist())` to confirm your list of columns is valid

Comment: @EdChum thank you, I'm gradually learning how to use this site.  Since I'm new(no credits) can't insert photos of the data frame.  I just went back and removed the spaces in the notepad++ I had saved the function in and ran it again.The error only shows '\n' character for the 'POPEXTIMATE2013' this time.I'm pretty sure, it's not from the implementation (the way I wrote it). thanks.

Comment: pardon me it is the same error,just didn't look carefully. Please ignore the question.

Comment: Definitely, you need to pass more arguments to [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), how is data separated? what about the header?. Please include the first lines of your input file so we can debug the issue.

Comment: @Rafa, thank you. The list of col names is too long for this entry, what's a good way to post it here?

Comment: Just simply include a subset of columns, for example the first and last two. The main thing is to understand the dataframe format.

Answer (score 2):

I think the column names in the code have typo. The pattern is 'POPESTIMATE201?' and not 'POPESTIAMTE201?'

Any help with shortening the code will be appreciated. Here is the code that works -

```
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
def answer_seven():
    cdf = census_df[(census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50)].set_index('CTYNAME')
    columns = ['POPESTIMATE2010', 'POPESTIMATE2011', 'POPESTIMATE2012', 'POPESTIMATE2013', 'POPESTIMATE2014', 'POPESTIMATE2015']
    cdf['big'] = cdf[columns].max(axis =1)
    cdf['sml'] = cdf[columns].min(axis =1)
    cdf['change'] = cdf[['big']].sub(cdf['sml'], axis=0)
return cdf['change'].idxmax()
```